# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2610Library

Tags: android, lottie

I think there is a bug in android studio  when i try to use **[lottie library](http://airbnb.io/lottie/android/android.html#getting-started)**

from **lottie introduction** :

> Gradle is the only supported build configuration, so just add the dependency to your project build.gradle file:
>
> dependencies {
>       ...
>       compile 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.2.5'
>       ... }

I've added the dependency , but project is not sync and not being built.

-here is complete error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2610Library'.
Unable to unzip 'C:\Users\ramin\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.support\animated-vector-drawable\26.1.0\abdf83a0192c03ff190f941c6c885af18d257a2c\animated-vector-drawable-26.1.0.aar' to 'C:\Users\ramin\.android\build-cache\6b7ed6c6f6a25dd18477727c16a13e0789c57b4e\output'
```

any idea ?

**build.gradle :**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "chavosh.com.bztebuses"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.github.devlight.navigationtabstrip:navigationtabstrip:1.0.4'
compile 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.3.0'
compile 'com.github.boxme:squarecamera:1.1.0'
compile 'com.minimize.library:seekbar-compat:0.2.5'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.github.medyo:fancybuttons:1.8.4'
compile 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.2.5'
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/gigamole/maven/" }
    maven { url  "http://dl.bintray.com/ahmedrizwan/maven" }
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}
}
```

Comment: show your **`build.Gradle`**

Comment: @NileshRathod i edited just now

Comment: try to updated your play service version

Comment: @hassanmoradnezhad try to update support dependency to 26.0.2 from 25.0.0

Comment: @NileshRathod thanks , i will check it, but compile'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.2.5' causes this error and when i delete this line from dependencies , project syncs and built correctly

Comment: @hassanmoradnezhad remove **`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'`** than try

Comment: @Sanjeet it doesn't work

Comment: @NileshRathod it doesn't work , too